# Representation of Fourier Transform's vectors

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis, matlab

I am just learning FFTs and I am trying to debug a problem in MATLAB.

I think I don't understand how is ***MATLAB***'s FFT function handling the polynomial powers, or I am doing something wrong manually. My problem is that it seems that positions 1 .. n-1 are reversed.

OK, here is a very simple example:
p(x) = x and I would like to compute the 4th order FFT

On paper it would be:

```
w0 = 1; w1 = i; w2 = -1; w3 = -i;
p(w0) = 1; p(w1) = i; p(w2) = -1; p(w3) = -i;
```

and for me it would mean the following in vector form:

```
p = [0,1,0,0]
fft(p) = [1,i,-1,-i]
```

But what happens is this:

```
fft(p)

ans =

   1.0000                  0 - 1.0000i  -1.0000                  0 + 1.0000i
```

It means that somehow MATLAB is looking at the roots of unity in a 0,3,2,1 order. Why is this happening or is it me who is doing something wrong?

**Update**

I'm even more confused now that I tried it in Maple and Wolfram Alpha.

In ***Maple*** it returns:

```
v:=Vector[row]([ 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 ], datatype=complex[8]);
FourierTransform(v);
Vector[row](4, {(1) = .500000000000000+0.*I, (2) = 0.-.5000000000*I, (3) = -.500000000000000+0.*I, (4) = 0.+.500000000000000*I})
```

In ***Wolfram Alpha*** it is:

```
fft([0,1,0,0])
returns:
{0.5, 0.5 i, -0.5, -0.5 i}
```

So to sum up, here is how it looks totally different by using 4 different methods:

```
polynomial: x^2 or [0,1,0,0]
FFT on paper: [1, i, -1, -i]
in MATLAB: [1, -i, -1, i]
in Maple: [0.5, -0.5i, -0.5, 0.5i]
in Wolfram Alpha: [0.5, 0.5i, -0.5, -0.5i]
```

Comment: Have you compared your working definition (normalization and all that) of the FFT with the definition of whatever software you're using?

Comment: Your "FFT on paper" is a bit suspect in that the more common formulation of the discrete Fourier Transform in engineering circles (which MATLAB caters to) gives the values of $f(x)$ at $\exp(-i 2\pi k/N)$ for $0 \leq k < N$.  **Your** evaluation is at $\exp(+i 2\pi k/N)$ and so you get the complex conjugate of what MATLAB is giving you.  The inverse discrete Fourier Transform has a factor of $1/N$, but, as J.M. has already noted, the normalization also can be different in different formulations.  Maple and Wolfram Alpha probably use $1/\sqrt{N}$ in both directions instead of $1/N$ in one.

Comment: @Dilip: I know for a fact that *Mathematica* (and thus Wolfram Alpha) does use the $\frac1{\sqrt N}$ normalization; at least for *Mathematica*, you have the `FourierParameters` option to tweak if the default convention isn't to your liking...

Comment: The short answer to this question: "FFT implementations vary."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically everything has already been said in the comments. There are two aspects of the discrete Fourier transform that require a choice of convention: where to put the minus sign in the exponent and where to put the normalization factor(s). Both can be distributed arbitrarily between the transform and its inverse; that is, the transform can be defined as

$$\hat a_k=n_1\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n\mathrm e^{-\sigma2\pi\mathrm i kn/N}$$

and its inverse as

$$a_n=n_2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\hat a_k\mathrm e^{\sigma2\pi\mathrm i kn/N}$$

with $\sigma=\pm1$ and $n_1n_2=1/N$. Usual choices are to distribute the normalization symmetrically, that is $n_1=n_2=1/\sqrt N$, or to put it all into one of the transforms so that the other one doesn't require normalization. See also the last few paragraphs in [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) for pros and cons of the different conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now it's more clear. I found out that in Mathematica you can set it to work like in "paper", you have to set FourierParameters to 1, 1.